# TSQL Subquery filter to performance problem

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I'm working on this query. When I assign a date filter from subquery to main query, the response time increases from 1 second to 4.5 minutes.

I don't know how to solve this problem and fix my query. I'm writing the query and the methods I've tried.

Thank you for your help.

My query:

```
select
    START_DATE as DATE,
    [MINUTE] as MIN,
    map1.LT,
    ISNULL((SELECT
                (SELECT CAST((main.MIN) AS FLOAT)) /
                    (
            (nullif(
                (select cast(
                    (select 
                        sum(MIN2) 
                    from fooTable2 d2 
                        CROSS APPLY (select Top(1) LT from FooMap2 where x = d2.x) k2
                    where k2.LT = map1.LT
                        **-- PROBLEM CODE START**
                        and YEAR(d2.DATE) = YEAR(main.DATE) and MONTH(d2.DATE) = MONTH(main.DATE)
                        **-- PROBLEM CODE END**
                    ) as float)),0))
    as XX,
    ....... 

    ......
from Table1 main
OUTER APPLY (select Top(1) LT from FooMap where x = main.x) map1
```

I tried creating a virtual table.

But not working.

```
declare @child table ([Year] smallint, [Month] smallint, [Total] float,[LTCode] nvarchar(20))

insert into @child ([LTCode],[Year],[Month],[Total])
(select 
    k2.LT,YEAR(d2.DATE) as YIL,MONTH(d2.DATE) as AY,sum(MIN) as SURE
from DURUS d2 
    CROSS APPLY (select Top(1) LT from FooMap2 where x = d2.x) k2
group by k2.LT,YEAR(d2.DATE),MONTH(d2.DATE))
... 
    ....
(select [Total] from @child where [YEAR] = YEAR(main.DATE) and [MONTH] = MONTH(main.DATE) and [LTCode] = map1.LT)
```

What should I do ?

Comment: There is a lot of information that could improve on the possibility of someone adding a helpful comment or a solution. (1) What is "not working" with your virtual table? Is it just as slow, generating an error, or ???  (2) What is the relationship between the `main` table and the `DURUS` / `footable2`? It is obviously many-to-? -- the question is, is it many-to-many (when grouped by year/month), or many to one (grouped by year/month/map1.LT)?  Sample data and expected results would also help.

Comment: NOTE: If the problem with the virtual table is that it does not help with the speed of the query, replace the `@table` variable with an actual `#temp` table, and add appropriate indexes to speed the data retrieval. Also, if you have more than a few rows in your `@table`, the query plan being generated is likely bad, since SQL Server assumes only one record exists in an `@table`. Using the `#temp` table will generate correct statistics, which can greatly improve performance.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plans in your question.

Comment: Can you modify the tables, e.g. adding indexed computed columns for the year and month to `Table1` and `fooTable2`? Depending on the usage, a single column containing `Year * 12 + Month` may suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem is the data model. You need to filter on month and year but store your data as a DATE, DATETIME or similar. **There is no easy way to make this fast**:

```
and YEAR(d2.DATE) = YEAR(main.DATE) 
and MONTH(d2.DATE) = MONTH(main.DATE)
```

WHERE FUNCTION(Input) = FUNCTION(Input) forces a scan against each table, having two such filters means you are touching/evaluating each  value (d2.date and main.date) twice for each row in each table. To fix this your best options include:

1. Adding a persisted computed column on each table for year and month then add the appropriate index (on year, month with all columns involved in your query added as Include columns.
2. Use an indexed view to pre-join Durus and main, not simple but doable.
3. Learn how to create and utilize a correctly indexed calendar table. This will require some effort but will also change your career.
4. Work other filters on the Left side of your joins...
   For example: add a WHERE clause after `from fooTable2 d2` to filter out any additional  rows before the join.

Answer (score -1):

Common ways to optimize:

1) remove calculations from the left in filters

2) render subqueries in separate temporary tables or in intermediate CTE queries

3) do not use table variables

4) in the early stages try to filter as much data as possible before connections